# How To Format Nested Tables Resulting From Nested Loops In ASP Classic

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, html-table, nested-loops

I am working with nested loops in a Classic ASP (VB Script) page, and I would like some input as to the most efficient way to display the data.

The data is currently displayed in a 'parent' table and a 'child' (nested) table.
The 'parent' table (from the outer data loop) contains the "Goal," and the 'child' table is formed by the "Objective" which uses the Goal ID to select the correct Objective data.

Thus, the inner table is formed using the Objective data, along with its dependent Implementation data, Outcome data, and Outcome Review data, so that there are 4 columns in the inner table: Objectives, Implementation, Outcomes, and Objective Review.

Here is an image of the basic idea.
[image: basic nested table design]

In the image, the Objective loop iterates x number of times within the parent table's column, forming the child table.
Is there a dependable way to align the columns for the parent and child tables, so that the column headers in the parent table will align to the matching columns in the child table?

Many thanks

Comment: You probably need to specify fixed widths for your table cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need for nested tables here. Just repeat the parent information for each child row, or put in blank cells for all except the first child, or -- if you know from the outset how many child rows there will be -- put in rowspans for the parent cells.

Here's a very rough outline of how I usually do it, i.e. putting in blank cells for all except the first child. (In reality, the for-next loops might be `do until rs.EOF` or some such, with the data coming directly from the database rather than being loaded into an array, but the idea is the same.)

```vbs
for p = 1 to nParent
   isTop = True
   for c = 1 to nChild
      response.write "<tr>"
      if isTop then
         response.write "<td>" & parent(p,1) & "</td>"
         ' etc.
      else
         response.write "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
      end if
      isTop = False
      response.write "<td>" & child(c,1) & "</td>"
      ' etc.
      response.write "</tr>"
   next
next
```